# Преобразовать строку которая выводится построчно по одному символу, нужно собрать ее в полноценную строку

Tags: python, python-3.x

В общем проблема заключается в том, что я подключаюсь к вычислителю через КОМ-порт, и получаю от него информацию с его консоли, забираю ее с помощью модуля Serial, которую в дальнейшем разбиваю на символы с помощью команды .read(1), далее записываю полученные данные в data. Потом эту дату я вызываю и печатаю в питоновскую консоль она мне выдает ее посимвольно, питон показывает, что каждый символ находиться в своем списке и как из этого закомпилить строку я не знаю. Примера кода нет, т.к. не желательно его распространять.

Comment: просто приведите пример, как сейчас символы в своем списке и что хотите получить

Answer (score 0):

```
symbols = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print("".join(symbols)) # abc
```